# Makefile: How to create both static and shared libraries in C?

Tags: c, makefile

Ladies, gentlemen, hello.

I'm trying to create a Makefile in C which will create two libraries
One static,one shared.
So far my Makefile works for the static part.

Projet file structure:

```
//root
//root/src
```

An other point to mention, this Makefile also creates *.o in my root project directory and the /src dir.
What to do so it only creates object files inside the /src directory ?

Makefile:

```
SNAME   =   libmy_printf_`uname -m`-`uname -s`.a
DNAME   =   libmy_printf_`uname -m`-`uname -s`.so
SRC     =   $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ     =   $(SRC:.c=.o)
CC      =   gcc
RM      =   rm -f
CFLAGS  =   -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Werror -g3 -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -L. -l$(NAME)

STATIC:     $(OBJ)
            $(CC) -c $(SRC) 
            ar r $(SNAME) $(OBJ) 
            ranlib $(SNAME)

DYNAMIC:    $(OBJ)
            $(CC) -c $(SRC)
            $(CC) -shared -o $(DNAME) $(OBJ)

.PHONY: my_printf_static
my_printf_static:       $(STATIC)

.PHONY: my_printf_dynamic
my_printf_dynamic:      $(DYNAMIC)

.PHONY: all
all:                    my_printf_static my_printf_dynamic

.PHONY: clean
clean:
                        $(RM) $(OBJ)
.PHONY: fclean
fclean:                 clean
                        $(RM) $(SNAME) $(DNAME) 
.PHONY: re
re:                     fclean all
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your makefile can be boiled down to this:

```perl
NAME    :=  libmy_printf_$(shell uname -m)-$(shell uname -s)
SNAME   :=  $(NAME).a
DNAME   :=  $(NAME).so
SRC     :=  $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ     :=  $(SRC:.c=.o)
CFLAGS  :=  -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Werror -g3 -fPIC
LDFLAGS :=  -L.
LDLIBS  :=  -l$(...)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

all: $(SNAME) $(DNAME)

$(SNAME): $(OBJ)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(DNAME): LDFLAGS += -shared
$(DNAME): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(SNAME) $(DNAME)

re: fclean all
```

There are multiple things that you should know:

- Don't use back-quotes commands, use the `$(shell)` built-in function in conjunction with the `:=` assignment operator to prevent commands being re-run multiple times (unless this is the desired behavior).
- Use only one `.PHONY` special rule, placed above all rules, and list them there.
- Redefining `$(CC)` or `$(RM)` variables like you did is pointless since they already contain what you wanted here.
- You wrote `-l$(NAME)` but you didn't define a `NAME` variable. I change it to `$(...)` since I couldn't guess what you really wanted here, don't forget to handle this.
- Use the name of the targets to be created as the name of the related rules. That way Make won't recreate the targets unless you really want it (by calling the `clean`, `fclean` or `re` rules explicitly).
- `-L` flags and `-l` flags should not be mixed in the same variable, unless placed at the right place in the linking command. Actually you didn't even used them. I explicitly separated them in the `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` built-in variables, as per Make implicit rules.

If you have any questions, go ahead.

---

As discussed in the comments, if you need to remove the `-fPIC` flag from the compilation flags for the static library, you should consider building object files in different directories:

**EDIT**: I added your `my_printf_static` and `my_printf_dynamic` rules:

```perl
NAME    :=  libmy_printf_$(shell uname -m)-$(shell uname -s)
SNAME   :=  $(NAME).a
DNAME   :=  $(NAME).so
SRC     :=  $(wildcard src/*.c)
SDIR    :=  build-static
SOBJ    :=  $(SRC:src/%.c=$(SDIR)/%.o)
DDIR    :=  build-shared
DOBJ    :=  $(SRC:src/%.c=$(DDIR)/%.o)
CFLAGS  :=  -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror -W -g3
LDFLAGS :=  -L.
LDLIBS  :=  -l$(...)

.PHONY: all clean fclean re my_printf_static my_printf_dynamic

all: my_printf_static my_printf_dynamic

my_printf_static: $(SNAME)

my_printf_dynamic: $(DNAME)

$(SNAME): $(SOBJ)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

$(DNAME): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(DNAME): LDFLAGS += -shared
$(DNAME): $(DOBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(SDIR)/%.o: src/%.c | $(SDIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(DDIR)/%.o: src/%.c | $(DDIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

$(SDIR) $(DDIR):
    @mkdir $@

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(SDIR) $(DDIR)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(SNAME) $(DNAME)

re: fclean all
```

Comment: Often, `.a` are built without `-fPIC`, whereas `.so` with. In this case you may like to build objects with different compiler flags into different directories. Same applies for debug and release versions.

Comment: Oh man you just make my life a little brighter after 5h on this. I forgot to remove the "-l$(NAME) which was from a former Makefile I modified to fit the needs of this projet. Thank you so much for such detailed explanation. I would tip my fedora to you if I had one !

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Yes, here it would be better to use two different directories for object files since the flags to compile them need to be different. I just tried to stay simple while staying close to the original Makefile to not lose the OP.

Comment: @Chnossos So how would one do this exactly ? Where could I find nicely explained doc on Makefiles ins and outs ? Also how to use your solution adding the rules (standalone from all) my_printf_static and my_printf_dynamic ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteBouhier I edited my post to add a working makefile that compile each project's object files into a different directory and use your `my_printf_static` and `my_printf_dynamic` rules.

Comment: So where did you learn all this ? I'm interested in doing this without the 'training wheels' so to speak.Thanks again.  http://41.media.tumblr.com/58832d47076c8ee8d8a563662eef5bce/tumblr_mi2pm1iaBg1r8lg7to1_1280.jpg

Comment: I learned by reading some parts of the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and trying many things myself. Always striving for cleaner and clearer Makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

> What to do so it only creates object files inside the /src directory ?

Don't run the compiler twice. Your `STATIC` and `DYNAMIC` rules both depend on `$(OBJ)`, which will cause those files to be built by `make`'s implicit rules. Then, immediately after that you run the compiler again *within* those rules. Just take those lines out.  `make` normally prints the commands it's going to run, so you should see why it's happening in your build log.